# Which is the correct steeltoe connector for Redis in VMWare(PCF) Application Service

Tags: vmware, pcf, steeltoe

Looks like there three connector nuget packages available from steeltoe https://www.nuget.org/packages/Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Steeltoe.Connector.CloudFoundry/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.ConnectorCore/. I have an ASP.NET Core application in .net core 3.1. Which one I should select now? Also can i get detailed documentation of each of these packages. Looks like Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore need .netcore3.1 and the other two simply requires .nestandard2.0. Any idea why is it so? Ideally all reusable libraries target .netstandard2.X, if I am not wrong

Answer (score 1):

For Steeltoe 3.0 use `Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore` **and** `Steeltoe.Connector.CloudFoundry` - https://steeltoe.io/docs/3/connectors/usage#cloud-foundry

For Steeltoe 2.x use `Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.ConnectorCore`.

As far as the targeting goes, Steeltoe 3.0 is focused on .NET Core 3.1+, so we aren't intentionally building compatibility for anything older on that branch. There may be some cases where we're targeting `netcoreapp3.1` and could be targeting `netstandard2.0`... We've already dialed back several packages, though it doesn't look like ConnectorCore has been adjusted yet, we'd have to look at it to see if we can.

If you use anything that came before .NET Core 3.1, you should use Steeltoe 2.x, which is still maintained.

Comment: Thanks. https://steeltoe.io/docs/3/connectors/redis says, "you need to add a reference to the appropriate Steeltoe Connector NuGet package and a reference". I think it is better to give some description on how to select the appropriate nuget package as we have two here Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore and Steeltoe.Connector.CloudFoundry

Comment: Fair point, added [an issue](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Documentation/issues/66) to track this improvement to the docs